# Is there a pre-loader for the Chrome browser that I can use to load chrome when Windows starts up?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

And I don't mean start minimized.

I mean something similar to the Firefox preloader.

Comment: You mean you want to auto-start Chrome at startup?

Comment: i guess but i want it to start in the task bar next the the date/time. And when i close out it stilk stays open. So when i want to open ot i dkntbhave to wait for it to load.